# Create high quality image with Rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I need to generate an image with a text that has a high quality

I have the following code, it works fine but the generated image is of low quality and the text is pixelated

```
image = Magick::Image.new(width_image, height_image)
draw = Magick::Draw.new
draw.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
draw.annotate(image, width_label_last_text, height_label_last_text, x_label_last_text, y_label_last_text, text)
image.format = "jpeg"
image.write("image.jpeg")
```

I need the generated image to be of high quality and not be pixelated when the image is zoomed

I have tried with density and quality but that does not work

```
image.write("image.jpeg") do
     self.density = 150
     self.quality = 90
end
```

any ideas?

Comment: It pixelates because when you zoom in on a [bitmap image](https://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/images/what-is-the-difference-between-bitmap-and-vector-images/) it is always limited by the dimensions you entered. So how far you can enlarge is still limited by the pixel dimensions. I would suggest to use [Vector](https://rmagick.github.io/rvgtut.html) graphics if you don't want pixelization when you zooming in.

Comment: "High quality" is an entirely subjective term. An image can be high resolution (a lot of pixels) and also low-compression (which reduces compression artifacts) and its really a matter of trade-off with file size. If you have to reproduce text as raster images then PNG tends to do better then JPG.